# Android Dynamically load Listview at scroll end?

Tags: android

I am loading a listview from Http server, 20 at a time ,**At the end of Listview I a want to load next 20 data from server** and this process will continue till data ends in server ,I used class that extend BaseAdapter to populate first 20 data .what should i do??

Answer (score 42):

This looks to be an elegant solution as well: http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/

It also implements an `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`, and uses an AsyncTask to load more content as soon as a certain threshold of remaining items in the current scroll view is reached.

Comment: Great solution! But I've decided to change `(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)` to `(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount)`.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work any longer. (As of 11th of April, 2016)

Answer (score 19):

Ok i have seen that this is a common problem, so i have made a **SMALL LIBRARY** with custom load more and pull to refresh ListView in **github**, please check this at **[here](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)**, all is very explained in the repository.

Answer (score 10):

You can implement an `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`, that gets informed and which allows you to load more data.

See e.g.

```
....
ListView.setOnScrollListener(this);
....
```

And then have a look at https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L287

Or take a look at the [List9 example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List9.html) from the sdk examples.

Answer (score 9):

Heiko Rupp's code is the best option for this problem.
 The only thing you should do is implement  `onScrollListener` and in `onScroll()`
 just check if there is an end of list by using the code

```
boolean loadMore =  firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount-1;
```

if true load your data with regular fashion..

thaks Heiko Rupp for this snippet  :)

Answer (score 9):

This is what I used to load more data at the end of the listview

```
        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
        int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
        int totalItemCount) {
        //Algorithm to check if the last item is visible or not
        final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if(lastItem == totalItemCount){                 
        // you have reached end of list, load more data             
        }
       } 
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,int scrollState) {
        //blank, not using this
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was accidentally trying to update a view from a non-ui thread. Pushing the ui update code to the ui thread resolved my issue!

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            // insert ui update code here
        }
    }
});
```