# Android listview with header and footer buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

folks!
I need to make such layout: I've got listview and I need to put buttons on top and on the bottom of it, i.e. when user scrolls list to the end, he can see bottom button, and when user is on the top of list, he can see top button. But when user is 'in the middle' of listview, he can't see those buttons.  I've got no idea how to do it. Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listSearchResults);

        LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();

        View header=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);

        btnBack=(Button)header.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBack.setEnabled(false);

        listView.addHeaderView(header);

        View footer=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);

        btnForward=(Button)footer.findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnForward.setEnabled(false);
        listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First create two layout file. like as `footer_layout.xml` & `header_layout.xml` and add footerview-headerview in list view

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.footer_layout, null);

list.addFooterView(listFooterView);


LinearLayout listHeaderView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.header_layout, null);

    list.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
```

Comment: how can you make custom your button?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and [addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) on your ListView

Comment: Try posting an example...and explain the issue with the adapter when adding a footer

Answer (score 1):

Check here:

[Android Dynamically load Listview at scroll end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065339/android-dynamicaly-load-listview-at-scroll-end)

This is with the help of list's footer and header. Basically, you use [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)
/[addFooterView ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29). Check all versions of the methods, since they allow you to have the view not being selectable.