# Android layout textview and listview combined

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to layout a home automation app. The top part of the screen will be custom status text (Garage door is OPEN, System is DISARMED, etc). Under the status text there will be a refresh link/button/list item. Something that the user can click on to refresh the status text. At the bottom will be a listview that will be links to other pages and links to actions such as "Security Page", or "Close Garage Door", etc. My question is, how do I configure the layout? I have tried several LinearLayouts, RelativeLayouts, nested layouts, etc, and none have worked so far.
Here is my main.xml as of now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/statustext">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/refresh">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@android:id/list" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The refresh link could just be an item of the listview, but I would like to style it differently so it stands out, such as a different color font or background. Or it could be a button. But it needs to be between the statustext and itemlist. And everything should scroll as one unit.

Is this possible?
[image: My Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this works?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="status" 
        android:id="@+id/statustext">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="refresh"
        android:id="@+id/refresh" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">
    </TextView>
    <ListView 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to have a scroll bar, use `ScrollView` to warp all sub-items. But `ScrollView` it self can host only one direct child so you'll need to wrap them all with a `LinearLayout` which has everything you want inside.

Answer (score 1):

Add you status text content to listheaderview.here is the link for that.
[Android listview with header and footer buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121186/android-listview-with-header-and-footer-buttons)
This way the whole list ll be scrolled with your status text.