# Custom listview in Android with an image at top

Tags: android, listview

I have an Android project that displays results, using a simple listview. What I need is to display an image at the top of listview as follows:

[image: Before scrolling]

[image: After scrolling]

Please note, the image on top, should be scrollable. Would you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is a ListView, why dont you put an ImageView right above it in the XML?

Comment: Because If I put an ImageView above ListView in the XML, it occupies too much screen, so I want it be scrollable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ListView.addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) to add a header view to the top of your ListView.

Answer (score 2):

List view has header and footer options. You can put your scrollable image view in one XML layout, inflate and use that as list view header.

You can get more info if you search for list view header. The quickest one I can get is

[Android listview with header and footer buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121186/android-listview-with-header-and-footer-buttons)