# How can i scroll a Listview within a scrollview?

Tags: android

Iam new to Android, iam developing an application with listview in a scrollview. According to my requirement i need to show some of views with vertical scrolling and below that a listview. I want to scroll the entire view and listview vertically, where as listview must scroll independently. I have googled for the solution but found that we should not use Listview in a scrollview.

I have tried An alternative to this, by replacing the Listview with the Dynamic LinearLayouts, that is also not working.

I tried doing the disabling the focus of the ScrollView when I touch the ListItem and viceversa, but i didn't get it.

I tried the below code to disable the focus of scroll view.

```
mScrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mScrollView.setFocusable(true);

mScrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);

mScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: it cannot be done... listView won't scroll inside ScrollView...

Comment: You should modify ur layout to have the listview below the scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

ListViews are not meant to be used inside a scrollview.

For your ref: [see this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6552)

Answer (score 0):

### do not nest ListView inside a ScrollView

if you have to do so, try the code below, it's also from StackOverflow answered by one guy.

```
public class Utility {
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() – 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you got to know from others..

ListView inside ScrollView Won't Work.

For the shake for solution,

You can add the other layout part...your `views` into one xml and `listview` in another

Then use `listView.setHeaderView(view);` to add your view layout as header of that.

Example Code :

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerlayout);
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
lv.addHeaderView(ll);

**[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121186/android-listview-with-header-and-footer-buttons)** or you can also search on internet for *Example for Listview with Header*