# Force an ExpandableListView to move other items down

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, expandablelistview

My layout is a ScrollView with some TextView and other controls and also an ExpandableListView.

What I want to do is When Expanding the ExpandableListView the controls which are below it move down and again upon collapsing, all the controls move up and only Group of Expendables become Visible.

The problem is when using `wrap_content` for expandView's Height the expanding of it shows nothing and just the indicator (little arrow) shows that it's expanded, and when explicitly use some numbers eg. 200dp, the lowest items of expandView not shown. (Because of using two Scrolling widget together).

Here's my simplified layout.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >
    <LinearLayout>
       //some controls
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lstDrugs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

//HERE is the point that wrap_content only shows the groups header

            android:layout_height=**"wrap_content"**
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="@drawable/dividergradient"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddDrug"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lstDrugs"
            android:text="Add" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you fix your posted XML first. You have 2 immediate child elements for your scrollview.  Also please explain what currently happens. It is not clear from your question.

Comment: I've just explained what's happening on question. This is the important part of my XML not all of it.

Comment: Ok, thanks that helps a bit. Please add android:fillViewport="true" to your scrollView and see if that helps. Chances are you will still have issues. ListViews and ExpandableList views will are also scrolling views so it creates problems nesting these inside a Scrollview.

Comment: Also try giving your ExpandableListView a layout weight=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121186/91055) thread.

The problem is with using List inside ScrollView. To handle it you should use a layout other than the ScrollView (eg. LinearLayout) and add other widgets as **Header** and **Footer** of the list. This would enable the scrolling of the view and also expanding of the List.