# Android ListView with fixed header and footer

Tags: android, android-listview, customization

How can I create a `ListView` with fixed header and footer?

I don't want the header/footer to scroll with the items in the `ListView`.

Is it possible that the header/footer is floating over the `ListView` so that the header/footer dont need to have a straight bottom/top background and the `ListView` items scrolls below the background of the header/footer view, but still show the first element of the list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it by using @blackbelt suggestion and a small ImageView with the source image being transparant with a tile background.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/lv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_above="@+id/tv_footer"
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/footer_bg"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Footer" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:text="Header" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iconView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lv"
android:background="@drawable/header_bg2"
android:src="@drawable/transparant_bg_tile" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/tv_footer"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="@drawable/footer_bg2"
android:src="@drawable/transparant_bg_tile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot from device
[image]

Answer (score 10):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29. Check this for addHeaderView(param).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29. Check this for addFooterView(param).

Example of the method usuage by inlfating a layout @ [Android listview with header and footer buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121186/android-listview-with-header-and-footer-buttons)

You can use addHeaderView and addFooterView for the list to add header and footer.

You can do as what @blackbelt suggested. I have used a relative layout instead of LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Footer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Graphical Layout snap shot

[image]

Comment: That works fine. I used this solution but added a transparant ImageView with a tile background for the sawtooth effect below and above the header/footer.

Comment: @Goran pls mark the answer by clicking on the tick once if it helps. It will heps others who visit the post

Answer (score 7):

Use a `LinearLayout`, add your header upon the `ListView` and the footer above. Gives the `ListView layout_weight="1"`

Comment: That worked and fits right into my linear layout without a lot of changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the header and footer separate Views which you locate over the top and bottom of the ListView. Then set the opacity for those Views.

Answer (score 1):

**create your custom header and footer with your list view code as below**

**header.xml file**

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView      
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="your custom height" // you may set default too
          />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**footer.xml file**

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**add where your listview**

```
 LayoutInflater inflaterHeader = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflaterFooter.inflate(
                    R.layout.header, list_view, false);
    yourListView.addHeaderView(header);

    LayoutInflater inflaterFooter = getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflaterFooter.inflate(
                    R.layout.footer, list_view, false);
    yourListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Answer (score 1):

we can set header and footer in this way also, i am setting header layout above listview and in same way we cans et footer below listview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/app_theme_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include layout="@layout/header_icuc"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly_header"
        android:background="#F3F4F6"
        android:divider="@drawable/contact_list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Create your own custom View using LinearLayout and ListView