# How to prase tree structure JSON and display in UI in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am very new to Android and I don't have a lot of knowledge about JSON parsing. 
I have tree structure JSON but am unable to parse and store it in class and I'm  confused how to display on the UI.

**Note: I have trying JSON Parsing Mannually, any libary for this, give me hints.  ::: unable to fetching in ui , I want to fetch data in to stricky header view. Any idea, I have store separately subcategory1, 2,3,and 4 in different class as class list because i have just four subcategory every category.**

Below is code snipped showing what i've done thus far, but i am not sure that works or not, could anybody help me with how to store data in java class and how to access and display it on UI.

UI Structure: Every Category as Stricky Top.(Problem: During Show data on This View)

```
Category1
     Sub Category 1
       data
     Sub Category 2
       data
     Sub Category 3
       data
     Sub Category 4
       data
Category2
     Sub Category 1
       data
     Sub Category 2
       data
     Sub Category 3
       data
     Sub Category 4
       data
.
.
.
```

I have JSON Data ,Structure Image, that i have json.https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvjJo.jpg
 **JSON Data:** [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/YT1H22PS)
[image]
What i have done during parsing in android: I have added data on separate class for sub categories class like commclass, callsiclass, text class here.

Getting All ads in these list;

*display all data same every category and subcategory. how to display respective data from class.*

Thanks in advance. I'd appreciate if anybody could help out with the appropriate tricks parsing these type of JSON data in android.

Comment: Make a Pojo class with the same field names as is Json and then make  an ArrayList of that pojo class type and add the json data in it.

Comment: what problem you are getting with current code ?

Comment: But Sir, I have not experience in using pojo class, could you give me some idea, how to use it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, I have not display data properly on UI, every category have display all data but i want data display particular category and associate sub category with data.

Answer (score 1):

A little tip on the way. If you get tired of doing the JSON-parsing manually you can use a library instead.

GSON is pretty good, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. With this library you only make a Java-class matching the JSON attributes, and GSON will automatically parse your JSON-input. See the URL for examples.

Even have a gradle dependency for easy add: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Add the above to your build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: The author asks several times about tips for JSON-parsing. "I'd appreciate if anybody could help out with the appropriate tricks parsing these type of JSON data in android." and "Note: I have trying JSON Parsing Mannually, any libary for this, give me hints."

Comment: Here, I am parsing manually, is that correct? asking. if i am doing correct, Please give me some idea, how to display on stricky top header list that data as respective category->subcategory.

Comment: I don't have time to test if it is correct. I would rewrite it using GSON. For informasjon on sticky headers list, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713046/how-to-make-sticky-section-headers-like-ios-in-android

Comment: I already populated stricky header list, but data populated problem.

Comment: Ok. Create a class that matches the JSON structure. As you might have done already. Then add GSON as a dependency in your Android proejct, in your build.gradle like this: "compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3". Once GSON is in place, use GSON: Gson gson = new Gson(); gson.fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class); As stated in the answer to this question giving a GSON example.