# Load more data from database and show in listview android

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I want to load data when ScrollView reach at the threshold. First, I want to show last 20 rows from database and show in ListView then after using SwipeRefreshLayout load another 20 rows get from database and show in ListView and so on...

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure on ListView but in RecyclerView you have to overrride `mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {..}`, inside that there is `onScrollStateChanged` which you implement your logic. Like if `(totalItem==20)&&(totalitem==currentVisibleItem+previousSeenItems"...` , then `loadMoreFromDB() ...`

Comment: have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065339/android-dynamically-load-listview-at-scroll-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is called [EndlessScrollListener](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews). You will have to extend the class `EndlessScrollListener` and implement the `onLoadMore` method.

```
public class MyEndlessScrollListener extends EndlessScrollListener {

   @Override
   public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
        loadData(page);  
   }
}
```

And set the listener on the listView :

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
```

You can use the other constructors of the `EndlessScrollListener` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to load more data at the end of the listview

```
 listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
        int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
        int totalItemCount) {
        //Algorithm to check if the last item is visible or not
        final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if(lastItem == totalItemCount){                 
        // you have reached end of list, load more data probably call your database to load more data            
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,int scrollState) {
        //blank, not using this
        }
        });
```

Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398921/dynamic-listview-adding-load-more-items-at-the-end-of-scroll) may help you